# Problemas al utilizar Script para subir archivos de Google Drive

Tags: javascript, html, script, drive

Estoy implementando un Script para subida de archivos a mi Google Drive desde una pagina web (En este caso la utilizare para plataforma educativa).

Mi script funciona correctamente, pero al momento de ver el archivo subido me aparece la leyenda que no existe ese tipo de formato, sabiendo que son archivos .PDF y .JPG.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
 function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('form.html');
}

function uploadFiles(form) {
  
  try {
    
    var googledrive = "Pagos Estudiantes";
    var folder, folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(googledrive);
    
    if (folders.hasNext()) {
      folder = folders.next();
    } else {
      folder = DriveApp.createFolder(googledrive);
    }
    
    var blob = form.myFile;    
    var file = folder.createFile(blob);    
    file.setDescription ("Subido Por " + form.myName);
        
    return "Archivo Subido Con Exito ";
    
  } catch (error) {
    
    return error.toString();
  }
  
}
```

HTML:

```
<form id="myForm">
    <input type="text" name="myName" placeholder="Su Nombre..">
    <input type="file" name="myFile">
    <input type="submit" value="Subir Archivo" 
           onclick="this.value='subiendo..';
                    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(fileUploaded)
                    .uploadFiles(this.parentNode);
                    return false;">
</form>

<div id="output"></div>

<script>
    function fileUploaded(status) {
        document.getElementById('myForm').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = status;
    }
</script>

<!-- Include the Google CSS package -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons.css">
 
<!-- You can also include your own CSS styles -->
<style>
 form { margin: 40px auto; }
 input { display:block; margin: 20px; }
</style>
</style>
```

Espero puedan ayudarme saludos.

Answer (score 0):

- Elemento de lista

Espera e intenta abrir los archivos de nuevo más tarde
Espera unos instantes: si ves el mensaje "Error temporal (502)" cuando intentas abrir archivos en Drive, significa que los archivos no están disponibles temporalmente. Como este tipo de problema suele ser temporal, espera un poco e intenta abrir los archivos de nuevo.

- Elemento de lista

Consulta Google Workspace Status Dashboard: si se ha producido una interrupción conocida en Drive o en los servidores de Google, aparecerá en Google Workspace Status Dashboard como un punto rojo junto al nombre del producto afectado. Haz clic en el punto para ver más detalles sobre el problema.

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).